# How can I unlock the Club LOL?

Tags: animal-crossing-new-leaf

Sharing my town with younger sibling. We have all shops but no Club LOL. I never saw Dr. Shrunk after the T&T upgrade (we now have the TIY upgrade).

If he did visit and we missed him, will we get another chance for Club LOL? Also no animal neighbor approached me to suggest public works projects only the ones that were available at the beginning of game.

Answer (score 7):

If you missed Dr. Shrunk after you upgraded to T&T the project will show up in the Public Works.

[Source](http://animalcrossing.wikia.com/wiki/Club_LOL)

Answer (score -1):

If you did miss Dr. Shrunk, don't worry! It will show up a a public works project.